# ¿Cómo enviar un FormCollection en método POST en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Este es el código que tengo, pero envio solo `String`, ¿cómo lo cambio para enviar un `FormCollection`?

```
public String peticionUrlPost_2(String url, FormCollection parametro)
{
    HttpWebRequest HttpWRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    HttpWRequest.Headers.Set("Pragma", "no-cache");
    HttpWRequest.Timeout = 300000;
    HttpWRequest.Method = "POST";
    HttpWRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    byte[] PostData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parametro);

    HttpWRequest.ContentLength = PostData.Length;
    Stream tempStream = HttpWRequest.GetRequestStream();
    tempStream.Write(PostData, 0, PostData.Length);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    String respuesta = readStream.ReadToEnd();
    tempStream.Close();

    return respuesta;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué tecnología utilizas? ¿MVC? ¿WebForms?

Comment: Yo utilizo MVC.

Comment: ¿Te importaría si limpio tu código quitando los comentarios? Esto para que el código sea más claro, la pregunta más corta y más entendible.

Comment: No tranquilo no le veo ningún problema

Comment: ¿Estás iniciando con ASP.net MVC ? Esto te será de utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY prepara pop-corn y ve por unos refrescos que eson 4 horas 4 minutos y 4 segundos maratónicos de un workshop sobre dicho framework. ¡Desde cero! Por cierto, el código fuente se encuentra dentro de la descripción del video.  Saludos :D